# How to setAttributes in Gutenberg block?

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I try to make a Gutenberg plugin but I have problem to set a value of attributes.
I npm this template
`npx @wordpress/create-block example-plugin --template @ryanwelcher/multiple-blocks-template`
because I want create a multiblock plugin.
the problem is where and how register attributes.

I register it on block.json:

```
 "attributes": {
        "content": {
            "type": "string",
            "selector": "h2"
        }
    },
```

Then I used it on edit.js

```
 export default function Edit({attributes: {content}, setAttribute}) {
      const blockProps = useBlockProps();

     return (
      
         <p {...useBlockProps()}>
             <input value={content} />
               <TextControl label="Question:" value={content}
                allowedFormats={["core/italic"]}
                onChange={x => setAttributes({content: x})} >
             {__('larum ipsume', 'page-builder')}
         </p>
     );
 }
```

this method work but I have an error.
I cannot write all sentence but just first letter and it refresh my input.

Comment: I have the same problem... Everything is work but it doesnt save the attributes! I think it must be some import

Comment: The function you are deconstructing from `Edit()`'s arguments is missing an `s` - you should be receiving an error in the JS console detailing that `setAttributes is not defined`. Additionally, with no `source` argument specified in your `block.json` configuration the attribute should be stored in an HTML comment, but you've specified a `selector` argument which might be causing an unexpected behavior. Try correcting the typo and removing `"selector": "h2"` from your `blocks.json` file.